# UIMenu/UIAction not displaying image

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst

I am having issues with UIContextMenus in iOS 16 and Catalyst.    The following code displays the menus, but not the images.   I'm confused.

```
extension CapoButton: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {
    func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
            return UIMenu(title: "test", image: UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), identifier: .capoButtonMenu ,options: UIMenu.Options.displayInline, children: [
                UIAction(title: "subtest 1", image: UIImage(systemName: "star.circle")!) {_ in
                    print("fred 1")
                    
                },
                UIAction(title: "subtest 2", image: UIImage(systemName: "star")!) {_ in
                    print("fred 2")
                    
                }
                ])
        }
    }
}
```

The result is

[image: menu output]

Neither of the images in the UIActions display nor does he title/image of the primary menu.   I have tried the UImage with and w/o the unwrap (!).

Comment: Add this to your question not in comments

Answer (score 1):

Context menus on Mac Catalyst do not show images. From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaction/3335177-image:

> Only the context menu system supports the display of an image, and only when the app is running in iOS.

Comment: Seems to be correct. Very sad though.

Answer (score 0):

Finding that context menus in catalyst are not predictable. They work for some UIView type and not others. Will likely need to create my own popups.